# "apiserving@google.com" suddenly owner of my Google App Engine project

Tags: google-app-engine

Today I saw that I have "apiserving@google.com" as an owner of my Google App Engine project, and I cannot understand why it ended up there. I have tried to find any documentation related to it, but a search won't give me anything.

The only hit I have on "apiserving@google.com" as owner is a link (http://grokbase.com/t/gg/google-appengine/1519zm7na4/a-apiserving-google-com-is-suddenly-appeared-on-account-list-as-another-owner-of-my-own-project) to someone asking the same question.

I consider this question answered by Adrián. I removed an user that was owner to my application, and it was replaced with apiserving@google.com. The user disappeared after the fix was put into production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are aware of this issue. We have confirmed that this happens when a deleted account is added to the project. As the deleted account's information cannot be loaded, apiserving@google.com is used as the default one.

The engineers are working on it but there is no ETA on this. However, I'll update this thread when the fix goes into production.

**UPDATE**

The fix went into production on 5th February and @patrick has confirmed that the issue has been solved.

Comment: I assume the same is happening when you have an account as a project member and then remove that account? If so, I think that is what happened in my case.

Comment: Yes, that user should come from that action. I have voted up your comment because adds some useful information to my answer.

Comment: The fix has gone into production, could you confirm that the user has disappeared from your project?

Comment: Yes, the user has disappeared from my project. Thank you.